# Bracha on Hallel On Rosh Chodesh

Tags: halacha, minhag, rosh-chodesh-new-month

The last Tosafos on Masechet Arachin Daf 10 amud Aleph and continuing to amud Beis https://www.yutorah.org/daf.cfm/6039/arachin/10/a/ make a compelling case to recite a Bracha on Hallel. Many Sefardim and Ashkenazim do not, al pi the Rambam and other rishonim. If I recall correctly, The Rambam learns this from the Minhag of Aravos on Hoshhana Rabba, where we do not make a bracha. I was wondering if anyone knew any teirutzim to Tosafos' questions and proofs, especially their question they ask on Masechet Taanis Daf 28 amud Beis about the Amora Rav who initially objected when he heard a town reciting Hallel on Rosh Chodesh. He wanted to stop them from doing so, but when he saw that they skipped he said Minhag Avoseyhem Byadeyhem. Tosafos points out that if we don't recite a Bracha on a Minhag then he would have noticed at the beginning when they made a Bracha on Hallel and known it wasn't a minhag.
Also, what would Tosafos say the difference is between the Minhag to bang Aravos and recite Hallel? (Maybe Minhag avoseyhem bydayhem is stronger than a Minhag Neviim with a known starting date?)

Comment: "Rambam and other Rishonim" Which Rishonim agreed with the Rambam? The [nearly?] universal practice in all of Europe and North Africa during the period of the rishonim was to say a blessing, at least betzibbur.

Comment: Basically, I did a quick Google search before I posted this and also saw it brought b'sheim Rashi. Also the Minhag in EY was to say without a Bracha. I don't have seforim handy to look up if the Rashi is on those dappim, and they are slightly hard to read on this screen. I assumed that those communities where only the Chazan recites the Bracha to be motzie the tzibbur were making a pshara between the two shitos...

Comment: lots of assumptions here... Rashi did say a bracha actually, just a different Nusach from most. And I didn't say only the chazzan said it but that it was only said when saying hallel betzibbur; it wasn't just a compromise.

Comment: https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/05-01-12/ that's what I found. I don't know where the Rashi is, if it exists. I'm in the process if editing this comment. They quote a number of Minhagim where only the Shliach Tzibbur recites the Bracha. Is this mentioned in the Rishonim? If not, is it a pshara?

Comment: The most comprehensive listing of Rishonim on this topic is in Alei Hadas (in a footnote about the custom in Tunisia)